# check radio button as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have several checkboxes:
a- bezorgen 
b- afhalen.

if Afhalen is checked then the checkbox betaal op rekening has to be checked.

But now only the first time when afhalen is checked the radio button betaal op rekening is checked. But if you go to bezorgen and then back to afhalen the radio button betaal op rekening is not checked anymore. But it has to be checked.

I have this:

```
    @if (GetBoolean("bdCanOrderOnAccount"))
{
string ischecked = GetString("User.bdDefaultPickupOrDelivery.Value").Equals("afhalen") ? "checked" : null;
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="radio" value="PAY1" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID"  class="pull-left"  @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY1")){ 
  <text> checked="checked" </text>
  }>
  <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a" class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodebankaccount", "Betaal op rekening")</label>
</div>
}
<!--
  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="radio" value="PAY2" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY2a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID" class="pull-left" @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY2")) { <text> checked="checked" </text>          }>
    <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY2a" class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodeideal", "Betaal online via iDeal")</label>
  </div>
                                    -->
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="radio" value="PAY3" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID" class="pull-left" @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY3")) { 
  <text> checked="checked" </text>
  }>
  <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a" id='labelPay' class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodepickup", "betaal bij afhalen")</label>
</div>
</div>
@if (GetBoolean("bdCanOrderOnAccount")){
<script>
  $(function () {                                
  $('#EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a').parent().hide();  
  $("#EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a").prop('checked', true); 
  //alert('test')                          



    });





</script>                             
}
<script>
  $(function () {       
  if ($("#levering-optie-afhalen").prop("checked")) {
                    alert('true');
  $("#EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a").prop('checked', true); 

       alert('false');

  }
  });
</script>
```

so with this:

```
   <script>
  $(function () {       
  if ($("#levering-optie-afhalen").prop("checked")) {
                    alert('true');
  $("#EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a").prop('checked', true); 

       alert('false');

  }
  });
</script>
```

I check if the radiobutton afhalen is been checked.

Thank you

NIels

so if this is checked:

```
 <input type="radio" name="levering-opties" id="levering-optie-afhalen" value="afhalen" checked="@ischecked">
```

Then this also has to been checeked:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="radio" value="PAY1" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID"  class="pull-left"  @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY1")){ 
  <text> checked="checked" </text>
  }>
  <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a" class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodebankaccount", "Betaal op rekening")</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm lost with all these unreadable names, code and bad indentation BUT only one radio button can be checked by group (name attribute), so i'm not sure what are you expecting?!...

Comment: Please format your code properly, as previously asked

Comment: oke, have done that

Answer (score 0):

Oke,

this was the solution:

```
@if (GetBoolean("bdCanOrderOnAccount")){
<script>
  $(function () {                                
  $('#EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a').parent().hide();  
  $("#EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a").prop('checked', true); 

  $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
  {
  if ($('#levering-optie-afhalen').is(':checked')) 
  { 
  $("#EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a").prop('checked', true); 
  }
  });
  });                                
</script>                                                                   
}
```